# How can i show a Ticker on iOS device Home screen and lock screen?

Tags: ios, iphone, homescreen, ticker

I am creating a App in which i need a ticker for Stocks on iPhone's home screen. [image]

Is it possible in iOS? Please guide me.

Comment: It is not possible in iOS

Comment: @LucaD have you any documents to prove it ?

Comment: My experience also say it's not possible, at least if you're not jailbroken. Never saw any documentation about it but since iOS uses the sandbox concept for any app, including the "home screen"(Springboard), this is another fact pointing to this been impossible to do.